# Class-Field-theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am currently on Jürgen Neukirchs Algebraic Numbers theory and have some problems understanding his non-cohomological approach on class field theory. To introduce the notation would cost tremendous amount of time so I am only referring my question to Neukirch-readers. 
To prove the multiplicativity of his Reciprocity map he formulates two lemmas. For the prove of the second one he uses the "Norm map", which is a homomorphism from the units of the maximal unramified extension of L to the units of the maximal unramified extension of K.(Those elements which are mapped to Zero under a "Henselian valuation" corresponding to a Field are called its units) But since the maximal unramified extension of L is infinte over the base field k, one cannot have a "Henselian valuation" v_K for it because those "Henselian Valuations" are only defined for fields with finite degree over the base field k. So what are the units of a infinite extension L|k?

Comment: Every element of $L$ lies in some finite extension of $k$, say $M$, and is a unit in $L$ if and only if it's a unit in $M$.

Comment: Thanks, this already helped me a lot! But there is still something in his second lemma for the reciprocity map, that I don't understand: Neukirch claims, that for proving this lemma, one can assume u, u_i,i=1,2...r to be elements of U_M(M a finite Extension of K contained in the maximal unramified extension of L). I just don't understand why it suffices to prove this lemma just for u, u_i being elements of U_M. Any hint would be appreciated!